# How can I unpack a sprite sheet into multiple images?

Tags: tools, spritesheet

I need to take a sprite sheet and convert it into multiple images, one for each frame of the sprite sheet.

How should I go about this? I would prefer an offline method or a tool to do so -- I found [Alferd SpriteSheet Unpacker](http://www.alferdspritesheetunpacker.forkandbeard.co.uk/forkandBeard/apps/AlferdSpritesheetUnpacker/Download.aspx), but it is really slow on Windows 7 and does not seem to respond well at all.

Comment: I reworded your question so it is asking how to solve (what I presume to be) your specific problem rather than asking for a list of tools others are using, as the latter type of question is a poor fit for this site.

Comment: I'm the author of 'Alferd Spritesheet Unpacker' can you post a link to the spritesheet you're trying to unpack and I'll see why it's so slow. I developed and tested it on Windows 7 so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @ForkandBeard Here is the spritesheet. http://i.imgur.com/R1MPY.png . When I click on Select All > Export Selected. Nothing seems to happen it just hangs, and I tried sleeping on it but no luck.

Comment: @AivanMonceller thanks for posting the spritesheet. It's really small, I managed to unpack it in under a second running on Windows 7. I can't replicate the issue all I can suggest is make sure you're using ASU version 8 and you have permission to write to the folder you're trying to export to...

Comment: @ForkandBeard I know this is getting a bit off topic. But I tried to debug your work. (Just for the purpose of knowing the error). It stops when showing the folder browser dialog. I am not sure why. But I never see the folder browser dialog when clicking Export on ``cmdExport_Click``

Comment: @AivanMonceller interesting. Doesn't look like an exception was thrown then. I've just found some reported issues with `FolderBrowserDialog` in Windows7 when not running as administrator. Have you tried running ASU as administrator? Failing that if you want to debug it I'm happy to send you the source.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4464/discussion-between-forkandbeard-and-aivan-monceller)

Comment: If you don't mind an online solution, http://imagesplitter.net/ is as easy as it gets (provided the spritesheet is actually a regular grid, like the one you've posted). Just upload your image, select `SPLIT IMAGE` tab, choose the number of rows and columns (and the images format) - and that's pretty much it.

Comment: If the spritesheet is a bunch of regularly sized images, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can do this like split up an image into pieces. For example, [the commands for cropping a bunch of tiles.](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile)

Comment: Based on the answers this is getting, I'm closing it as "Which technology to use" since that's all people are suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shoebox is a great tool for this purpose and rather flexible.

http://renderhjs.net/shoebox/extractSprites.htm

It's AIR based, so you can use it on OSX or Windows.

It's drag/drop automagic at it's best.

Answer (score 4):

I just can't replicate the issue with `FolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog` hanging, so I've created a new version of the app (version 9) which has a new 'Prompt for Export Folder' option. Unchecking this option removes the need for the dialog box.

You can download version 9 from my site [Alferd Spritesheet Unpacker version 9](http://www.alferdspritesheetunpacker.forkandbeard.co.uk/forkandBeard/apps/AlferdSpritesheetUnpacker/Download.aspx).

On the 'Options' form untick the 'Prompt for Export Folder' check box and now ASU will just export the files to whatever directory path is in the long textbox at the bottom of the main form.

(If you don't want to change this option every-time you can set `PromptForDestinationFolder` to `false` in the `.exe.config` file)

Comment: Unfortunately, even with the PromtpForDestinationFolder unchecked, it still hangs. I am testing with this spritesheet (note that I converted it to PNG before dragging it into your unpacker): http://www.funorb.com/img/images/game/central/dev_diary/sprite_sheet_full.gif

Comment: It also hangs when I click `about...` in options. I am guessing the program has trouble opening additional windows.

Comment: @ForkandBeard. FYI, I think I experienced this issue on Windows 10, but I was able to work around it by clicking Alt+Tab. Apparently, the "Select Folder" dialog was showing up, but did not steal focus from the main window. And, since the main window was waiting for the dialog, it seemed "frozen."